# How to display a message before auto refresh div using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to display a message before an auto refresh div. I have created this code for the auto refresh.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
 if setInterval(function() {
   $("#pagere").load(location.href + " #pagere");}, 10000);             
 });
```

I also need to display a message like `"page auto refresh in 3 sec..."`.  How can I do that?

Comment: am working in an auction website... bidding made at any time so user have to knw refresh will happen in 3 sec like tat so wont give alert message will show any other popup :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :)

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
      var alertTimeSec = 3000; //alert time in ms
      var delayTimeSec = 10000; //time delay to refresh in ms
            setTimeout(function () {
               alert("3 Sec more")
            }, (delayTimeSec-alertTimeSec));
            setInterval(function() {
            $("#pagere").load(location.href + " #pagere");}, delayTimeSec);    
    });
```

Comment: Yes,In place of alert you can have a kind of toaster or custom designed slider pop-up.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
    setInterval(function()
    {
        $("#pagere_container").load(location.href + " #pagere");
    }, 3000);
</script>

<div id="pagere_container">
    <div id="pagere">
        page auto refresh in 3 sec...
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
setTimeout(function() {
   $('#load_status').show();
}, 5000);
$("#pagere").load(location.href + " #pagere");}, 10000);
```

-this will give you 5 sec of timeout before refresh

Comment: thank....setTimeout(function() {   $('#load_status').show();}, 5000);  what actually it works. my query how to display it